# Windows computer not able to find Raspberry Pi 0 2 over USB

Tags: usb, pi-zero, windows, pi-zero-w-2

I'm trying to set up my Raspberry Pi 0 2 over USB. To do this, I've followed guides like [this one](https://artivis.github.io/post/2020/pi-zero/) (I've looked at multiple, they all have the same instructions), and have correctly edited both `config.txt` and `cmdline.txt`. However, when I try to ping or ssh into the Raspberry pi, I get an error saying `No such host is known`. The most annoying part is, I know for sure that the pi is set up properly. I know this because when I tried to connect to the Pi on my friend's computer, a Mac (again, over USB), it works fine, and can connect without issue. Some guides I've found recommend installing [Bonjour print services](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL999?locale=en_CA), which didn't make a difference for me. Overall I'm kind of out of ideas here, and not really sure what the issue could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the issue was a missing driver, just not Bonjour print services. After some more searching, I stumbled upon [this guide](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-connect-raspberry-pi-to-laptop-or-pc-usb/#additional-configuration-options-for-windows-users) which mentioned another driver that might be missing, for RNDIS. Turns out, that was my issue! A guide to installing those drivers can be found [here](https://wiki.sipeed.com/hardware/en/maixsense/maixsense-a075v/install_drivers.html). It's worth noting that when the guide tells you to select an `.inf` file, there are two options and it doesn't tell you which one to pick. I tried both, and `RNDIS.inf` didn't seem to work, but `rndis11.inf` did. Whether or not that will be the case for everyone, I do not know.